# Django 1.4 Pagination with a query

Tags: django, pagination, python-2.6, django-1.4, django-q

I'm trying to get pagination working following the example in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/. I'm using query and can't seem to pass the query data to successive pages. The first page returns my query limited to 10 results as expected, but the next page simply returns a blank table.

- Versions: Django 1.4.4 and python 2.6.6

Code:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

def search(request):
    query_string = ''
    found_entries = None
    if ('q' in request.GET) and request.GET['q'].strip():
            query_string = request.GET['q']

            entry_query = get_query(query_string, ['id', 'address', 'itemcode', 'qty', 'description', 'metatags' ])

            found_entries = inventory.objects.filter(entry_query).order_by('-qty')
            paginator = Paginator(found_entries, 10) # Show 10 items per page

            page = request.GET.get('page')
            try:
                    found_entries = paginator.page(page)
            except PageNotAnInteger:
                    # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
                    found_entries = paginator.page(1)
            except EmptyPage:
                    # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
                    found_entries = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)


    return render_to_response('dynamite_frontpage.html', {"found_entries": found_entries})
```

URL:

```
(r'^search/$', 'dynamite.views.search'),
```

My template is setup correctly, when I exclude the query and display all results pagination works - eg:

```
def search(request):
    found_entries = inventory.objects.all().order_by('-qty')
    paginator = Paginator(found_entries, 10) # Show 10 items per page      

    page = request.GET.get('page') 
    try:
            found_entries = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
            found_entries = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
            found_entries = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render_to_response('dynamite_frontpage.html', {"found_entries": found_entries})
```

Thanks in advance.

Search function:

```
def normalize_query(query_string,
                findterms=re.compile(r'"([^"]+)"|(\S+)').findall,
                normspace=re.compile(r'\s{2,}').sub):
''' Splits the query string in invidual keywords, getting rid of unecessary spaces
    and grouping quoted words together.
    Example:

    >>> normalize_query('  some random  words "with   quotes  " and   spaces')
    ['some', 'random', 'words', 'with quotes', 'and', 'spaces']

'''
return [normspace(' ', (t[0] or t[1]).strip()) for t in findterms(query_string)] 

def get_query(query_string, search_fields):
''' Returns a query, that is a combination of Q objects. That combination
    aims to search keywords within a model by testing the given search fields.

'''
query = None # Query to search for every search term        
terms = normalize_query(query_string)
for term in terms:
    or_query = None # Query to search for a given term in each field
    for field_name in search_fields:
        q = Q(**{"%s__icontains" % field_name: term})
        if or_query is None:
            or_query = q
        else:
            or_query = or_query | q
    if query is None:
        query = or_query
    else:
        query = query & or_query
return query
```

Comment: It refers to an earlier function as part of my search logic. I'll add the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, InvalidPage, EmptyPage

def search(request):
    found_entries = inventory.objects.filter()

    if request.GET.get('q'):
        query_string = request.GET.get('q')
        found_entries = found_entries.filter(
                id__icontains=query_string
            ).filter(
                address__icontains=query_string
            ).filter(
                itemcode__icontains=query_string
            ).filter(
                qty__icontains=query_string
            ).filter(
                description__icontains=query_string
            ).filter(
                metatags__icontains=query_string
            ).order_by('-qty')

    paginator = Paginator(found_entries, 10) # Show 10 items per page

    try:
        page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
    except ValueError:
        page = 1

    try:
        found_entries = paginator.page(page)
    except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        found_entries = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render_to_response('dynamite_frontpage.html', {
        "found_entries": found_entries,
    })
```

In your template:

```
<input name="q" type="text" value="{{ request.GET.q }}">
```

Template tag test:

```
<form class="form-searchbar" method='get' action='/search/'>
    <input name="q" type="text" value="{{ request.GET.q }}">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I still get the same result. Page one returns my query data, page 2 table is blank.

Comment: Hi Catherine, here is the form which contains the table + pagination. I 16 entries that are captured by this query.

Comment: Hi Catherine, great that gets me closer. The only thing is when I go to the next pages I lose the filter. For example when I search by router, the first page shows only routers, but page 2 shows routers and switches. I can see what you are trying to do though.

Comment: Hi Catherine, I tried your suggestion and I don't get any results now :( This is how I added the template tag, is this what you meant? See template tag test.

Comment: @JasonK  Can you just send me your whole project to my gmail? It will be easy for me to trace your codes and fix it easily

Comment: No problem, it's on a server at work give me a little bit and I'll send it to you. My email is in my profile, you can email me your address if you like. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, must be hidden. Can you see it now in the about me section?